# Why my Store Procedure is accepting NULL but not empty string i.e ' '

Tags: mysql, parameters, null

```
    ~CREATE PROCEDURE (ARG1 INT, ARG2 INT)
    BEGIN
    if ARG2 IS NULL Then
        #STATEMENTS
    ELSE
        #STATEMENTS
    END IF;
    END//
    
    CALL PROCEDURE ('119', '101')
    CALL PROCEDURE ('119', NULL)
    CALL PROCEDURE ('119', '')
```

CALL PROCEDURE ('119', '')  is not working, it should work like CALL PROCEDURE ('119', NULL)

Comment: Is there an error when using the empty string? How do you know the empty string isn't accepted? As it stands your question has no answer, more info is needed I think.

Comment: Please edit and expand the question. Don't use the comments for code.

Comment: Show SP code, or at least the parameters definition part.

Comment: See the code, is it helping

Comment: " is not working" - what does that mean? As far as I see, the procedure you've shared does not perform any action, regardless of the input for the second argument